# How to secure new public proof of work blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I am fairly new to the bitcoin and blockchain technology and have recently started reading about it. So my understanding and the question bellow may not be very accurate.

As I have understood so far, proof of work is the basic building block for a bitcoin block chain and because of it, an attacker will have to produce more than 50% of the total compute power (i.e control more than 50% of the nodes)
in order to manipulate the block chain by being able to produce longest block chain consistently.

Now bitcoin guys were bit lucky as they were the first and nobody paid attention in there early days. Once bitcoin gathered momentum, number of honest nodes become predominant and system became inherently secure.

But now, how someone can start a new public blockchain (for completely different application) safely ? Because, if a new blockchain is floated with few mining nodes,
any attacker can come with more compute nodes and hijack the blockchain as there are small number of honest nodes.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on what you want to do. There are many implementations of Blockchain, each of them has its objective. Bitcoin was the first implementation of Blockchain. Bitcoin is a cryptocurrency and like Bitcoin, there have been developed many other cryptocurrencies.

However, the Blockchain technology would be useful to many things: for example, to control the vote in a distributed way in the elections. Because of that, there are many implementations of Blockchains.

- [Hyperledger Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a private Blockchain, where the acces to it must be controled
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.org/) is a public Blockchian to transfer assets. Anyone could create his tokens and start using them through the Ethereum network. So, you will use an existing Chain and attackers couldn't hijack you. I think that this would be a great start. If I were you, I'd continue reading [this](https://www.ethereum.org/token).

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the attack you are describing (51% attack), where existing miners hijack a new network there are a couple ways to avoid this.

### [Merge Mining](https://github.com/namecoin/wiki/blob/master/Merged-Mining.mediawiki)

The smaller chain includes block data in the larger chain (e.g. Bitcoin) so the blocks are mined with the hashpower of the larger network.

### Change the hashing algorithm

For Bitcoin, two rounds of SHA256 is the hashing algorithm. Because there is so much mining power, it is possible to get attacked fairly easily because Bitcoin miners can just point their existing miners to the small network long enough to execute an attack, and then switch back. This happened to Bitcoin Gold recently. So, use something other than SHA256 where there is already a lot of hashpower in terms of hardware out there.